# Accessing chrome V8 engine console running on a server

Tags: node.js, google-chrome, v8

I have a NodeJS application running on a server in forever mode and the **console.log** outputs from the application scripts are logged into the directory **~/.forever/** (as this is in the root directory, only read permissions are available to the log file in this directory). These logs are displayed in the server's chrome browser v8 engine's console through node-monkey at the address **127.0.0.1:50500**.

This server is behind a proxy.

Now, I want to see this logs from the server's V8 engine on a client browser. I tried to access it using the server's address followed by the port as below from the browser, but wasn't able to connect.

http://www.servers.addr.com:50500

I have also tried connecting to the server through ssh and performing **curl** on the command line to the localhost address above, but *as expected* it would only fetch the html content displayed in the browsers window.

So is there any way we can fetch the console logs from the v8 engine of the browser running in the server.

Comment: In documentation it tells how to use outside of localhost: https://github.com/jwarkentin/node-monkey be aware of security concerns.

Comment: @alandarev >> I don't want anyone to have unauthorized access to the data..

Comment: @alandarev >> I have updated the question, the application is running in forever mode and the console logs aren't actually printed on the console at the server because of forever mode. So is  there a way we can get the node-monkey's browser console on the ssh console window?

Comment: I suggest you make a clearer question, because it is misleading then.

Comment: @alandarev >> Thanks for pointing out, modified the question.

Comment: it might sound against guidelines, but your best bet is to resubmit the question, as it is now far from the front page, and I doubt anyone will notice... Just don't get a habit into spamming :)